# could not get query Selector inside <ng-template> in angular

Tags: html, angular, dom, queryselector, ng-template

I have table component.

I want to add a property to a  element when `[draggable]="true"`.

parent class

```
        <ngx-custom-table [value]="users" [draggable]="true">
         <ng-template #header let-columns>
          <tr> 
             // removed
          </tr>
          </ng-template>
         <ng-template #body let-data>
          <tr >
            <td>
            </td> 
          <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
         <tr>
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-custom-table>
```

child class

```
 ngOnInit() {
       console.log( (<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('ngx-custom-table'))); // this is defined
    console.log( (<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('tr'))); // but this is null
    
  });
```

Why  `(<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('tr'));` this is null??

How can I add a property to `<tr>` element?

Comment: Because the tr is inside a template, which is actually not rendered itself. When are you trying that selector? You might want to try it in the afterViewInit hook.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have an another issue,
I can log, `<tr>'s inside `<thead> . but i couldn't log `<tr>` insde `<tbody>` . Why?